# Rails6/Webpacker環境で外部JSファイル内でHTMLのIDを取得したい

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, erb

### 発生している問題

外部Javascript内で`document.getElementById`を使用しHTMLのIDを取得しようとすると`Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`　が発生します。

app/javascript/chk_waittime/index.js

```js
document.getElementById('post_waittime').onclick = function(){
  alert('index.js');
};
```

開発者ツールのコンソール画面

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    js index.js:1
    Webpack 5
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
index.js:1
    js index.js:1
    Webpack 5
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        <匿名>
        <匿名>
```

### 環境

- Ruby 2.6.3
- Rails 6.0.3

### Javascriptの構成

app/javascript配下の構成

```
app % find javascript
javascript
javascript/packs
javascript/packs/application.js
javascript/chk_waittime
javascript/chk_waittime/index.js
javascript/channels
javascript/channels/index.js
javascript/channels/consumer.js
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("chk_waittime")
import "bootstrap"
```

app/javascript/chk_waittime/index.js

```js
document.getElementById('post_waittime').onclick = function(){
  alert('index.js');
};
```

### html.erbの構成

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

app/views/shops/index.html.erb

```html
(省略)
<% if logged_in? %>
(省略)

<% else %>
  <ol class="shops">
    <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
      <%= render partial: "shop_not_login", locals: {shop: shop} %>
    <% end %> 
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

app/views/shops/_shop_not_login.html.erb

```html
<li class="shops">
  (省略)
  <%= link_to "待ち時間を投稿する", "#", id:"post_waittime" %><br>
</li>
```

### 外部Javascriptが動作していることの確認

app/javascript/chk_waittime/index.js

```js
alert('index.js');
```

ブラウザ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680)

Comment: リンク先で解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app/javascript/chk_waittime/index.js`を下記のように
`window.onload = function() {}` で囲うことで解決しました。
javascriptが読み込まれるタイミングが原因のようです。

変更前

```js
document.getElementById('post_waittime').onclick = function(){
  alert('index.js');
};
```

変更後

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('post_waittime').onclick = function(){
    alert('index.js');
  };
};
```

コメントいただいたリンク先の内容を参考に解決することができました。

[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680)